# Trigger SelectedIndexChanged event ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, dropdown, selectedindexchanged

I have a DropDownList inside a GridView. I want to make some updates on database inside the SelectedIndexChanged it's not being triggered.

PS: I tried all the solutions I found over internet but always the same problem.

Here is code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Accepté" ControlStyle-Width="90px">
       <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StateCode") %>' Visible = "False" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" Visible = "False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField >
```

And the code behind

```
protected void grwConsent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text != "&nbsp;")
        {

            DropDownList ddlState = e.Row.FindControl("ddlState") as DropDownList;
            if (null != ddlState)
            {
                ddlState.Visible = true;
                string stateValue = (e.Row.FindControl("lblState") as Label).Text;

                ConsentHelper.LoadConsentStatesInList(ddlState,"-----",stateValue);

                ddlState.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                ddlState.Items.FindByText(stateValue).Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }

}

protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Database Updates
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you binding data to the GridView inside an `IsPostBack` check?

Comment: protected void Search_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Requests = ObjectManager.GetObject();
        grw.DataSource = Requests;
        grw.DataBind();
}

Comment: Try adding `AutoPostBack=true` to the DDL

Comment: the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these properties to you DropDownList:

- `ViewStateMode="Enabled"`
- `EnableViewState="true"`
- `AutoPostBack="true"`

---

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
    ViewStateMode="Enabled" runat="server" ...
```